# Web scraping with google script (with google spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, html-parsing

What is the correct way to scrape an html page with google script?

```
<html class="gr__mcb_mu"><head></head><body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true"><table class="table table--decorated">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th><span class="visually-hidden">Currency</span></th>
        <th class="content-right">Buy</th>
        <th class="content-right">Sell</th>
    </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>AUD</td>
                <td class="content-right">25.71</td>
                <td class="content-right">26.74</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EUR</td>
                <td class="content-right">41.16</td>
                <td class="content-right">42.39</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>GBP</td>
                <td class="content-right">46.7</td>
                <td class="content-right">48.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>JPY</td>
                <td class="content-right">31.01</td>
                <td class="content-right">32.25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>USD</td>
                <td class="content-right">34.35</td>
                <td class="content-right">35.25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ZAR</td>
                <td class="content-right">2.68</td>
                <td class="content-right">2.81</td>
            </tr>
</tbody></table>
<p class="content-left"><small>MCB indicative rates (TT) against MUR on 03/05/2018</small><br></p><div style="background-color: rgb(255, 143, 0); display: none; color: white; text-align: center; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: auto; min-width: 100%; min-height: auto; max-width: 100%; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;"><span style="color: white; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;">You have turned off the paragraph player. You can turn it on again from the options page.</span><img src="chrome-extension://gfjopfpjmkcfgjpogepmdjmcnihfpokn/img/icons/icon-close_16.png" style="width: 20px; height: auto; min-width: 20px; min-height: auto; max-width: 20px; float: right; margin-right: 10px;"></div></body></html>
```

I want to get the second and the third row values of the table where the first row equals: `"USD"`. In other words, I want to get 34.35 and 35.25 as output.

My first attempted was hardcoding the query using [regex](https://regexr.com/) but it might break as soon as a tiny change is done on the html page. Is there a better way? (Inbuilt library or something like that? )

Comment: Contact them for an API, to both reduce their operational costs and improve the reliability of your requests.